# RL PPO action space clipping in openai's spinningup

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, openai-api

I'm currently using "spinningup" which was made by openai.
In spinningup, PPO and other RL algorithms are implemented. However, only for DDPG, SAC, and TD3 has variable named "action_limit".

I'm using PPO now and I also need to clip (give lower and upper bound) action since my robot is only working in [0, 200.0] range.
Is it because that algorithm PPO does not need action_limit different from DDPG, SAC,TD3?
or
Is it spinningup's mistake that they did not place action_limit on PPO?

or is there other clever way to make some bounds in here?

Answer (score 0):

I also thought it should be considered when you create the environment with the "spaces.Box", but when running the policy it also gets values higher than the box I entered.

If you look into the [Continuous_MountainCarEnv](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/continuous_mountain_car.py), it uses the following code in the self.step() to use the action (line 74):

```
force = min(max(action[0], self.min_action), self.max_action)
```

So, it limits the force input in the step, although it already created the action_space with the same limits (line 51):

```
self.action_space = spaces.Box(
        low=self.min_action,
        high=self.max_action,
        shape=(1,),
        dtype=np.float32
```

So, probably it is useful to consider the limits when creating the action_space and using the action itself. If you don't use this limit, the trained policy may result in actions higher than your limit, although they can be close to it.

Cheers!!